# Can't connect to database after code execution

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to solve one problem and it was suggested to run the following code to solve it:

```sql
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
GO
```

After executing it, I now can not even connect to the database, it gives error 26.

Can you tell me what the code does and how to get it back?

Comment: What was the problem you were originally trying to solve? Are you saying that now *(after you blindly ran the above code)* it has broken your instance?

Comment: I tried to save the table to Excel, but the query didn't work. To make the code work, it is advised to run this code.

Comment: Restore `master` from backup. You do have a backup, right....?

Comment: The problem has been resolved. It turned out that these commands stopped SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS). In SQL Server, Configuration Manager turned it on and everything worked.